# Get total count of nodes lesser/greater than some value in BST

Tags: java, binary-search-tree

I am having problem with my code. It is showing:

BSTNode'<'Golfer'>' cannot be converted into BinarySearchTree'<'Golfer'>'.

Please provide me some hints to fix my code.

```
public int countLowerScores(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree, int maxValue) {

    BSTNode<Golfer> node = tree.root;
    if (node == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int countLeft = countLowerScores(node.getLeft(), maxValue);
    int countRight = countLowerScores(node.getRight(), maxValue);

    return (node.getInfo() > maxValue ? 1 : 0) + countLeft + countRight;  

    }
```

Comment: Which line does the error come? When calling this function, seems like you are passing a BSTNode instead of BinarySearchTree

Comment: @Sara Please add BinarySearchTree class implementation as well. One more point if you already knew the total number of node in your BST then you no need to look for both lesser/greater. you can look for one and get the other one by subtracting it from the total number of node BST have.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have `countLowerScores` method that takes `tree` as a parameter. Now you cannot pass node to it. You can use BST Traversal and integrate through each node and compare the value.

```
    public int countLowerScores(BinarySearchTree<Golfer> tree, int maxValue) {

        Iterator<Golfer> iter; // Createts interator for comparision.
        int count = 0; // Counts the number of nodes.

        // Traverse the tree in inorder.
        iter = tree.getIterator(BSTInterface.Traversal.Inorder);

        // Get the nodes and compares to passed argument.
        while (iter.hasNext()) {
            if (iter.next().getScore() <= maxValue) {
                count++;
            };
        }
        return count;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what's with `BinarySearchTree` and `BSTNode`, but you must have the node, left child and right child of the same type.

That's the whole ideea of the tree, it is a recursive data structure, meaning root and  children can be treated in the same way. Here's an example:

```
class TreeNode {
  int val;
  TreeNode left;
  TreeNode right;
  TreeNode(int x) { val = x; }
}
```

And the method:

```
public int countLowerScores(TreeNode root, int maxValue) {
    if (root == null) {
        return 0;
    }

    int countLeft = countLowerScores(root.left, maxValue);
    int countRight = countLowerScores(root.right, maxValue);

    return (root.val > maxValue ? 1 : 0) + countLeft + countRight;

}
```

you are overcomplicating things with generics.

Comment: Thank you! It helped.